# Code to search and get client information

Tags: excel, vba, spreadsheet

I have an improvised customer registration spreadsheet inside Excel until I can develop one in the database like MySQL or Access, but after some changes I broke my code and I can't solve it.

It is a code to search for the client information by their full name and get their info if they are registered, but my spreadsheet only works on the base sheet of the service order, not on the customer's orders.

It is a work order spreadsheet, where I have the base OS sheet to make the new ones, and then I make a copy (by vba macro) for each customer of the week. But the search is only working and taking the information from the base OS, and putting it there, not the specific client OS.

I need it to work on all the sheets, including the one I'm trying to get the information from, and put this information on the right sheet. I tried to change the workbook calls from

`ThisWorkbook.Sheets("OS").Range("B10").Value`

to

`ActiveSheet.Range("B10").Value`

but it didn't work.

The code:

```
Sub search()
' search of data and information of registered clients
    Dim results As String
    results = MsgBox("Deseja buscar este cliente?", vbYesNo) 'message to confirm search
    
    If results = vbYes Then
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        
        client = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("OS").Range("B10").Value
        
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("db").Activate
        Dim lastLine As Long
        lastLine = ActiveSheet.cells(rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).row
        
        For i = 2 To lastLine
            If cells(i, 1).Value = cliente Then
                client = cells(i, 1).Value
                cAddress = cells(i, 2).Value
                cNumber = cells(i, 3).Value
                district = cells(i, 4).Value
                City = cells(i, 5).Value
                Contact = cells(i, 6).Value
                cpf = cells(i, 7).Value
                car = cells(i, 8).Value
                lPlate = cells(i, 9).Value
                renavam = cells(i, 10).Value
                km = cells(i, 11).Value
                
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("OS").Range("B10").Value = client
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("OS").Range("B11").Value = cAddress
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("OS").Range("F11").Value = cNumber
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("OS").Range("B12").Value = district
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("OS").Range("F12").Value = City
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("OS").Range("F13").Value = Contact
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("OS").Range("B13").Value = cpf
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("OS").Range("B15").Value = car
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("OS").Range("B16").Value = lPlate
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("OS").Range("F15").Value = renavam
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("OS").Range("F16").Value = km
            
                i = i + lastLine
            
            Else
                
                If i = lastLine Then
                    MsgBox "Cliente não cadastrado!" 'message for clients not registered
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("OS").Activate
                    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
                    Exit Sub
        
                Else
                End If
                
            End If
        
        Next i
    
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("OS").Activate
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        MsgBox "Busca efetuada com sucesso!" 'successful search and get informations message
    
    End If

End Sub
```

[image]

PS. The spreadsheet is in Portuguese

Comment: Are the sheets `CLIENT 1`, `CLIENT2`, etc just copies of the OS sheet with the client's information? Is it possible for a client to have multiple orders in the same week? Can two clients have the same name, or do you protect against duplication?

Comment: Your question is not so clear and your code do not clarify it. Do you want it to iterate between all existing sheets and use `.Range("B10").Value` for each such a sheet as `cliente`? Anyhow, there looks to be a typo. You defines `client = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("OS").Range("B10").Value` and then you use `If cells(i, 1).Value = cliente` (client vs cliente)..

Comment: Then, what the first MsgBox does validate? That the value in "B10" is the one to be used? \if yes, it should be stated in the prompt text. `results` it is good to be declared as `As VbMsgBoxResult`. And then use 'If results <> vbYes then Exit sub`. Maybe a warning MsgBox, too. In order to determine if the client has been found the `ElseIf` part is not the most appropriate way. You should eliminate it, create a Boolean variable and make it `True` when the client has been found. Then only check `If Not boolFound then MsgBox "Cliente não cadastrado!"`

Comment: It would need to iterate between all sheets and instead of `client = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("OS").Range("B10").Value` you will use `client = sh.Range("B10").Value`. Where `sh` is the sheet in the iteration: `For Each sh in Worksheets` `'do whatever is to be done` `Next`. But, if you will answer my questions I can try preparing an answer. But only if you answer on time. I will leave my office in about half an hour...

Comment: badodre, in my registration code, which the logic behinde is close to the one I was using for search it did not allow duplication. He compare the string text, to see if match's. There is no way to have the same customer in the same week, because the services made for him will be on the same OS, and hardly two clients will have the same name because the search is done with the person's full name, it's possible, but very very unlikely, its not something that i am worried. And yes, they are only copys made through vba macro.

Comment: FeneDuru, about the cliente vs client is a typo error that I had not seen (how i said, the spreadsheet is in portuguese, but not de code). As for the code not making sense, let me explain something: This spreadsheet was only for the base service order, and the client's' OS's were saved in another separate file on the desktop. Now I brought them all together in a single file.

Comment: So the code can be a little confusing because of that. In reality, it only worked before with the sheet OS because all clients had the sheet named OS. Now there are several sheets with different names for each client. And that's what I'm not able to find a solution to work again. And the first MsgBox just ask if you want to search this client and bring his information. And the "B10" cell is the one who has the name of the client to be searched.

Comment: In order to do what you need, the above code will search the "B10" cell value in "db" worksheet, too. Is this what you really want? If yes, I can prepare an answer. If not, you should clarify your need, from this point of view...

Comment: this is exactly what i need, to search for the B10 cell value in the "db" worksheet and put the information regarding that client in the respective cells of the OS if find's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try the next code. It iterates between all existing sheets (except "db" one) and do what the existing code does for the client **found in "B10**:

```
Sub searchOneSheet()
' search of data and information of registered clients
    Dim results As VbMsgBoxResult, sh As Worksheet, wsDB As Worksheet
    Dim client As String, lastLine As Long, boolFound As Boolean, i As Long
  
    results = MsgBox("Deseja buscar este cliente (""B10"" Range)?", vbYesNo) 'message to confirm search
    
    If results <> vbYes Then Exit Sub
    
    Set wsDB = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("db")
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    
    lastLine = wsDB.cells(rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).row
    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            client = sh.range("B10").Value
            For i = 2 To lastLine
                If wsDB.cells(i, 1).Value = client Then
                    sh.range("B11").Value = wsDB.cells(i, 2).Value  'cAddress
                    sh.range("F11").Value = wsDB.cells(i, 3).Value  'cNumber
                    sh.range("B12").Value = wsDB.cells(i, 4).Value  'district
                    sh.range("F12").Value = wsDB.cells(i, 5).Value  'City
                    sh.range("F13").Value = wsDB.cells(i, 6).Value  'Contact
                    sh.range("B13").Value = wsDB.cells(i, 7).Value  'cpf
                    sh.range("B15").Value = wsDB.cells(i, 8).Value  'car
                    sh.range("B16").Value = wsDB.cells(i, 9).Value  'lPlate
                    sh.range("F15").Value = wsDB.cells(i, 10).Value 'renavam
                    sh.range("F16").Value = wsDB.cells(i, 11).Value 'km
                
                    boolFound = True: Exit For  'since you said there are not double occurrences
               End If
            Next i
            If Not boolFound Then
                MsgBox "Cliente não cadastrado (" & client & " - " & sh.Name & ")!" 'message for clients not registered
            Else
                MsgBox "Busca efetuada com sucesso (" & client & " - " & sh.Name & ")!" 'successful search and get informations message
                boolFound = False
            End If
    'Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: it worked almost perfect. Except that, he is searching for all the worksheet that has in the spreadsheet, and not just the "active" one. For example, open a worksheet of the "client 3", put his name on B10 cell and search for the client informations on db. He searches and brings in the information perfectly, but then he searches for all the other clients worksheets as well.

Comment: @Vitória Lopes: "I need it to work on all the sheets, including the one I'm trying to get the information from..." would mean what I tried, I think. It is much easier what you specify now, but the logic of the code must be changed. When I will find some time, I will adapt it in the way I understood now.

Comment: I did an analysis of the code here, and I believe what might be causing this is the line "For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets", but I don't know what could be put in place without breaking the code.

Comment: In my comment about work in all the sheets I mean, the one I need to, because initially only worked on OS sheet. but I need them to work separately. I expressed myself badly, sorry

Comment: @Vitória Lopes: Please, check the updated code and send some feedback.

Comment: Now it's working perfectly. Thank you so much for your help, and sorry for the work.